# .htaccess rewrite parameters not passing to target page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, centos, varnish

I want to pass url parameters but parameters are not passing on to the desired page.

Earlier my site was hosted on cpanel and below code works successfully but after I shifted my site to VPS Server with Cent OS Webpanel with Varnish Cache and apache running on server, the parameters are not passed on target page/url.

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  

RewriteRule ^download/(.*).html download.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I want to run the url: `www.example.com/download/anything.html` 
and target url after rewrite is `www.example.com/download.php?q=anything` 
The problem is that rewriterule is working but parameters are not passed.

But if I use the below code the parameters are passing Successfully.

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_0-9-]+)$ download.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

or below code

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteRule ^(.*) download.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

and I am running the below url, the parameters are passed to target page successfully
`www.example.com/anything` 
target url: `www.example.com/download.php?q=anything`

but I want the URL in the following format `www.example.com/download/*****.html` replace *Asterisk Sign with actual query.

If I add some static text to the Rewrite url like `download/`(.*)`.html` the parameters are not passed to target page.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely new server has `MultiViews` options enabled by default. Place this line on top of .htaccess to disable it:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs before `mod_rewrite` and and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.